# Unexpected token import with React.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs

> Unexpected token import
>
> import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';

I have problem with this keyword in my jsx file. How to solve that? Iam using .NET 4.6 and React.NET 3.0.
Same with require keyword.

> ReferenceError: require is not defined